# Python list encoding and exporting to CSV issue

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, csv, beautifulsoup

I am trying out Python scraping for the first time so I'm kind of patching up codes from all over the place.

Right now I have encountered 2 issues that I do not know how to solve:

1. My `tbl` list outputs to `test.csv` into only the first cell and is not delimited as well even though I've specified the conditions in `.writer()`
2. The output into the CSV file has some encoding issues even though I don't see any when I output on my Python shell.

I am currently using Python 2.7

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import pandas as pd

site= "https://www.investing.com/currencies/usd-sgd-forward-rates"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = urllib2.Request(site,headers=hdr)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

px_table = str(soup.find('table', attrs={'id':'curr_table'}))
print type(px_table)
tbl = pd.read_html(px_table, encoding='utf-8')

with open('test.csv', 'w') as myFile:
    wr = csv.writer(myFile, delimiter=' ')
    wr.writerow(tbl)
```

output:

```
Unnamed: 0            Name     Bid     Ask    High     Low   Chg.     Time
0          NaN   USDSGDÂ ONÂ FWD   -0.85    0.15   -0.29   -1.19  0.75 9:40:00
1          NaN   USDSGDÂ TNÂ FWD   -0.50   -0.45   -0.35   -0.45 -0.08 9:43:00
2          NaN   USDSGDÂ SNÂ FWD   -0.30   -0.20   -0.29   -0.21  0.10 9:42:00
3          NaN   USDSGDÂ SWÂ FWD   -2.17   -1.69   -1.80   -1.80 -0.16 9:42:00
4          NaN   USDSGDÂ 2WÂ FWD   -5.32   -1.72   -3.58   -3.44 -1.22 9:43:00
5          NaN   USDSGDÂ 3WÂ FWD   -6.15   -4.35   -5.12   -5.17 -0.30 9:42:00
6          NaN   USDSGDÂ 1MÂ FWD   -8.53   -7.74   -8.00   -8.10 -0.17 9:42:00
7          NaN   USDSGDÂ 2MÂ FWD  -15.81  -14.81  -14.75  -15.15 -0.25 9:43:00
8          NaN   USDSGDÂ 3MÂ FWD  -25.00  -24.07  -23.53  -24.07 -0.40 9:42:00
9          NaN   USDSGDÂ 4MÂ FWD  -35.72  -27.72  -32.16  -32.37 -1.18 9:43:00
10         NaN   USDSGDÂ 5MÂ FWD  -46.53  -35.47  -40.00  -40.96 -2.41 9:42:00
11         NaN   USDSGDÂ 6MÂ FWD  -50.83  -48.67  -48.75  -50.00  0.94 9:42:00
12         NaN   USDSGDÂ 7MÂ FWD  -65.77  -53.06  -59.68  -58.69 -3.27 9:43:00
13         NaN   USDSGDÂ 8MÂ FWD  -79.41  -59.65  -66.98  -69.70 -6.61 9:42:00
14         NaN   USDSGDÂ 9MÂ FWD  -84.51  -73.85  -74.05  -79.19 -1.84 9:42:00
15         NaN  USDSGDÂ 10MÂ FWD -102.16  -75.06  -85.01  -87.28 -9.66 9:43:00
16         NaN  USDSGDÂ 11MÂ FWD -109.81  -84.92  -96.50  -96.31 -7.91 9:43:00
17         NaN   USDSGDÂ 1YÂ FWD -107.88 -103.13 -104.47 -107.00  2.63 9:43:00
18         NaN  USDSGDÂ 15MÂ FWD -140.08 -106.19 -132.00 -121.00  6.92 9:40:00
19         NaN  USDSGDÂ 21MÂ FWD -200.00 -151.00 -185.50 -180.50 14.00 9:40:00
20         NaN   USDSGDÂ 2YÂ FWD -196.50 -121.50 -162.40 -197.50 50.50 9:40:00
21         NaN   USDSGDÂ 3YÂ FWD -355.00 -306.00 -347.00 -330.00 20.00 9:43:00
22         NaN   USDSGDÂ 4YÂ FWD  145.00  211.00    0.00    0.00  1.00 31/07
23         NaN   USDSGDÂ 5YÂ FWD  117.00  187.00    0.00    0.00 -4.00 31/07
24         NaN   USDSGDÂ 7YÂ FWD   63.00  189.00    0.00    0.00 -1.00 31/07
25         NaN  USDSGDÂ 10YÂ FWD  -30.00  127.00    0.00    0.00 10.00 31/07
```

Comment: There's a specific directive concerning "why isn't this code working?" style of questions. Your ignorance thereof probably caused your question to be off topic.

Comment: haha, still trying to wrap my head around how this works here. as i mentioned above, the code is pretty much a patchwork of what i've found on the net. hopefully i can find a pattern after enough practice. dont really understand why people dont like this tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Pandas [`to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas-dataframe-to-csv) function to write your table. You can also specify a file encoding such as `utf-8` for the file:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

site = "https://www.investing.com/currencies/usd-sgd-forward-rates"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = urllib2.Request(site, headers=hdr)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

px_table = str(soup.find('table', attrs={'id':'curr_table'}))
df_table = pd.read_html(px_table, encoding='utf-8')[0]
del df_table['Unnamed: 0']
df_table.to_csv('test.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

This would give you a `test.csv` starting like:

```
Name,Bid,Ask,High,Low,Chg.,Time
USDSGD ON FWD,-1.35,0.65,-0.29,-1.19,0.25,12:10:00
USDSGD TN FWD,-0.54,-0.46,-0.35,-0.49,-0.12,11:11:00
USDSGD SN FWD,-0.43,-0.14,-0.29,-0.25,-0.03,12:11:00
USDSGD SW FWD,-1.99,-1.51,-1.8,-1.8,0.02,12:10:00
USDSGD 2W FWD,-5.63,-1.53,-3.58,-3.44,-1.53,12:11:00
```

This code also removes the unwanted `Unnamed: 0` column, and disables the writing of an index column to the CSV file.

---

Alternatively, you could remove the need for BeautifulSoup as `read_html()` will return a list of data frames for all tables that it is able to find:

```
import urllib2
import pandas as pd

site = "https://www.investing.com/currencies/usd-sgd-forward-rates"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = urllib2.Request(site, headers=hdr)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
df_table = pd.read_html(page.read(), encoding='utf-8')[1]
df_table.drop(df_table.columns[[0]], axis=1, inplace=True)
df_table['Name'] = df_table['Name'].str.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')
df_table.to_csv('test.csv', encoding='ascii', index=False)
```

This approach also forces the conversion of the `Name` column to be ASCII.

Comment: thank you so much for this! There are still 'Â's in the output file but I bashed around it by simply filtering it out.

Comment: The CSV file is written with a utf-8 encoding. If you opened the file in an editor that supports utf-8, it will show correctly. The alternative is to apply a conversion to ASCII, e.g. `df_table['Name'] = df_table['Name'].str.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')`